# Adjoint prefunctors

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

I have a functor and a prefunctor (not a functor) "in the inverse direction".

Can the notion of adjunction be generalized for prefunctors?

I remind that a prefunctor is a functor without the requirement to preserve identities (that is a prefunctor is required to preserve composition but not identities).

@Egbert asked me to describe my situation in more details. So I do below.

My real setting is the following: $(\mathsf{FCD})$ is a functor from the category $\mathsf{RLD}$ to the category $\mathsf{FCD}$ (see [this preprint](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/funcoids-reloids.pdf) for definition of these categories and functions); $(\mathsf{RLD})_{\mathrm{in}}$ is a prefunctor (not a functor) from the category $\mathsf{FCD}$ to the category $\mathsf{RLD}$. I suspect that $(\mathsf{FCD})$ and $(\mathsf{RLD})_{\mathrm{in}}$ may be in some sense adjoint (but I've seen a definition of adjoints only for functors not for prefunctors).

Comment: You can define an adjunction in any bicategory. For example, there are adjunctions in the bicategory of categories and profunctors, in the bicategory of spans of categories, etc.

Comment: When this was homework we would ask questions like: what is the setting? What do you exactly mean by prefunctors? *What have you tried and where did you get stuck?* I think these are also relevant questions here. For the best possible answer, please try to be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: @Egbert: I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you call "prefunctors" are more commonly known as [semifunctors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semifunctor). Adjunctions of semifunctors (or *semiadjuntions*) were defined and studied by Hayashi in [Adjunction of Semifunctors: Categorical structures in nonextensional lambda calculus](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397585900623), and studied further by Hoofman in [The theory of semi-functors](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-structures-in-computer-science/article/abs/theory-of-semifunctors/C68B85097361F39E4050E45C1E99BB93).